# block requests to website that use my server's ip address rather than my domain name

Tags: nginx, firewall

In my nginx logs, I can see requests being made using my server's IP Address, not domain name.

I can't think any valid reason for this, other than it being bots.

Is there a way I can block web traffic access to my site where they don't use the domain name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301884/nginx-reverse-proxy-only-allow-connection-from-hostname-not-ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do a "black-hole" like virtual host, which has a `server_name` directive your server's IP address and returns 404 (or .. 444). Something like this:

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name <the ip address of your server>;
    return      404;
}
```

HTTP 444 status code is pretty neat, you should consider using it:

> 444 CONNECTION CLOSED WITHOUT RESPONSE A non-standard status code used
>   to instruct nginx to close the connection without sending a response
>   to the client, most commonly used to deny malicious or malformed
>   requests.
>
> This status code is not seen by the client, it only appears in nginx
>   log files.